# Maven release plugin fails to parse password with special character

Tags: svn, maven, maven-release-plugin

I am implementing Maven release plugin in my project to automate our release process.
But the `release-prepare` task fails to checkin the code and errors out with this error

```
authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge
```

I tried all steps mentioned in http://mszalbach.blogspot.in/2011/02/maven-release-plugin-and-commit_05.html but none worked.

I am able to run all svn command via commandline successfully.

I am pretty sure that my svn urls are fine because i am able to checkin the code using maven scm plugin in same pom.

Any suggestions on how to go about solving this?

EDIT:

I just realised that release:prepare runs successfully with cached username/passwd. But if i give same user via `-Dusername=testUser -Dpassword=passwd` then it fails. Credentials are correct. Am i missing something while passing parameters?

EDIT2:

I spotted the issue, my password starts with `$` sign and maven is not parsing it properly thats why this issue is coming. How to take care of special characters in password which running maven command?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with `mvn --encrypt-password` command with a password containing `$`. Escaping came out as the solution:

Instead of `mvn --encrypt-password pa$$word` I used `mvn --encrypt-password pa\$\$word` to make it work.

To make sure how your OS deals with special characters type `echo pa$$word`.

Answer (score 2):

First, add a server element to your `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml` file.

```
<server>
    <id>your.subversion.host</id>
    <username>yourUserName</username>
    <password>yourPassword</password>
</server>
```

- If you make the id the subversion host (e.g. subversion.mycompany.com) then this set up will work with both the `maven-release-plugin` and the `maven-scm-plugin`.
- You may encrypt your password following the [directions](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html).

Then, add the following to the POM.  (Tip: we have this in our corporate parent POM.)

```
<project>
   ...
    <properties>
      <project.scm.id>your.subversion.host<project.scm.id>
    </properties>
</project>
```

References: [maven-release-plugin FAQ](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/faq.html#credentials) and [Maven settings.xml  configuration](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Servers).

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. But i am keen on passing username , password as parameter. I just realised that release:prepare runs successfully with cached username/passwd. But if i give same user via -Dusername=testUser -Dpassword=passwd then it fails. Credentials are correct. ANy clues here?

Comment: RE: your edit 2.  It's not Maven that's having problems, it is your operating system that is interpreting the '$'.  Try using the OS's way of escaping special chars.